# linefeed-treatment="preserve" not working for next line generating pdf via xsl-fo

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

My xml file

```
<entries>
 <entry ID="93" ENTRY_TYPE="Text1" ENTRYNM="First line:
  Second line
  third line
  fourth line" ENTRY_DT="12-Jan-2004"/></entries>
```

My xsl-fo

```
<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment='preserve'
      white-space-collapse='false'>
<xsl:value-of select="./entries/entry/@ENTRYNM"/>
</fo:block>
```

I am generating pdf that contains ENTRYNM which should preserve next line as shown in xml.

```
Like example:
First line:
Second line
third line
fourth line
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because of [Attribute Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize). The line breaks are getting normalized into spaces. The only way to preserve these is to use a character reference in the attribute value.

For example, if you have this XML:

```
<entry ID="93" ENTRY_TYPE="Text1" ENTRYNM="First line:
    Second line
    third line
    fourth line" ENTRY_DT="12-Jan-2004"/>
```

and this XSLT (omitted xsl-fo namespace for brevity):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">        
        <block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ENTRYNM"/>            
        </block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get this output (normalized):

```
<block linefeed-treatment="preserve">First line:     Second line     third line     fourth line</block>
```

If you change the line breaks to character references in your input:

```
<entry ID="93" ENTRY_TYPE="Text1" ENTRYNM="First line:&#xA;
    Second line&#xA;
    third line&#xA;
    fourth line" ENTRY_DT="12-Jan-2004"/>
```

the same XSLT now produces this output:

```
<block linefeed-treatment="preserve">First line:
     Second line
     third line
     fourth line</block>
```

---

Here's another visual example of the normalization...

If we take the first XML input example:

```
<entry ID="93" ENTRY_TYPE="Text1" ENTRYNM="First line:
    Second line
    third line
    fourth line" ENTRY_DT="12-Jan-2004"/>
```

and try to tokenize based on `&#xA;`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">        
        <block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@ENTRYNM,'&#xA;')">
                <token><xsl:value-of select="."/></token>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

we get a single `token` in the output:

```
<block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
   <token>First line:     Second line     third line     fourth line</token>
</block>
```

if we use the second XML input example (with the breaks replaced with `&#xA;` references), we get 4 separate `token`s:

```
<block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
   <token>First line:</token>
   <token>     Second line</token>
   <token>     third line</token>
   <token>     fourth line</token>
</block>
```